# How to open existing sqlite DB in QspatiaLite plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Using QspatiaLite plugin in QGIS I'm able to create a new database and work with it (load/edit/import/export data). But how can I add a connection to an existing database?
How to add an existing database to the drop-down-menu of the available database connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the same "New DB" button. If you mouse-over the button the tip says "(you can also load an existing one, just ignore the replace)".

It's very non-intuitive, and should be changed, but it works. When you point to an existing DB a warning pops up that the DB already exists and you must click "Replace" (despite the warning) then the existing tables load.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice the tooltip. I tried to use the 'New DB' button but I stopped going on when popped-upthe alert saying "A file or folder with the same name already exists in the folder sqlite. Replacing it will overwrite its current contents.". Another way to add a connection is loading a sqlite layer from the sqlite DB, using QGIS Layer > Add Vector Layer. I found this adds a new item in the drop-down menu of the plugin. Maybe a more intuitive UI would help. It's a very useful plugin!